# Bootstrap nav-tabs and active link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am facing issue with bootstrap4 nav-bar and active tabs. The tab and the contents are not active while clicking but when I invoke them indvidually by placing active class at each tabs they are working.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class= "col">
        <h2>Super world Leadership</h2>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#ironman"
                role="tab" data-toggle="tab">iron man, CEO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#spiderman" role="tab"
                data-toggle="tab">spiderman, CFO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#batman"role="tab"
                data-toggle="tab">batman, CTO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#hulk" role="tab"
                data-toggle="tab">hulk, Exec. Chef</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="ironman">
                <h3>iron man <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small></h3>
                <p class="hidden-xs-down">Our CEO, ironman</p>
            </div>
            
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="spiderman">
                <h3>spiderman <small>Chief Food Officer</small></h3>
                <p class="hidden-xs-down">Our CFO, spiderman, </p>
            </div>
            
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="batman">
                <h3>batman <small>Chief Taste Officer</small></h3>
                <p class="hidden-xs-down">CTO </p>
            </div>
            
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="hulk">
                <h3>hulk<small>Executive Chef</small></h3>
                <p class="hidden-xs-down">Award winning </p>
            </div>
        
        </div>
   
    </div>
</div>
```

Can some one guide here.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the part to actually fire the tab selection.   You're either going to need to javascript it or use the data-toggle attribute.

Take a look here for some details:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: Yes, I am using data-toggle attribute for every tab in the above attached script.

Comment: Hmm, it should be working for you then as it is here:    https://jsfiddle.net/ricktbaker/oa8sg54b/1/